# Is it possible to run and debug a GWT-Maven project in Super Dev Mode?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt

I have a core idea of `maven` and I want to take support of `maven` in `GWT` so I create a project using `GWT` and `maven`. currently to run this I have to `install` it and `manually deployed` it on tomcat server. its really a time taking process.

is it possible to `run` this `Gwt-Maven` project using `super dev mode`?

My FishingEntry.gwt.xml

```
 <module rename-to='WeeklyFishingInit'>

  <inherits name="ae.ead.fishing.common.FishingCommon"/>
  <entry-point class="ae.ead.fishing.init.client.FishingEntry"/>

  <source path="client" />
  <source path="shared" />
</module>
```

and pom.xml is

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.maven.plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <skip>false</skip>
                <!-- disableCastChecking>true</disableCastChecking -->
                <!-- disableClassMetadata>true</disableClassMetadata --> 
                <!-- draftCompile>true</draftCompile -->
                <!-- style>PRETTY</style-->
                <soyc>false</soyc>
                <optimizationLevel>0</optimizationLevel>
                <compileReport>false</compileReport>
                <!-- extraParam>true</extraParam -->
                <runTarget>FishingEntry.html</runTarget>
                <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
            </configuration>


    </plugin>
```

my Project structure is

[image]

and Error is

[image]

my target folder is

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `mvn gwt:run`? Doesn't it just work?

Comment: yes thomas i tried it, but problem is same. getting error on browser 503..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, that's how we run our GWT-Spring-Maven project. Add to your `pom.xml` the `gwt-maven-plugin` plugin ([link](https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html)), something like below:

**pom.xml**

```
<plugins>
<!-- rest of your plugins here -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <runTarget>com.example.Application/Application.html</runTarget>
            <!--<extraJvmArgs>-Xmx6G</extraJvmArgs>-->
            <!--<localWorkers>1</localWorkers>-->
            <hostedWebapp>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</hostedWebapp>
            <bindAddress>0.0.0.0</bindAddress>
            <i18nMessagesBundle>com.example.client.ApplicationMessages</i18nMessagesBundle>
            <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
            <debugSuspend>false</debugSuspend>
            <deploy>${project.build.outputDirectory}</deploy>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

do any configuration if required and run it with:

`mvn gwt:run` or `mvn gwt:debug`

Comment: thanks for reply but each time I have to install it ?

Comment: what you mean by "install it" ? On your application server (tomcat) ? No, it will run in super dev mode and a jetty will be instanciated.

Comment: each time I have to install pom.xm file.

Comment: Install the pom.xml file? Sorry I don't get it. How you install the pom.xml file???

Comment: after make some changes in Code to reflect these changes we have to run mvn install command in eclipse to create war file.

Comment: Ah ok I got it now. No, if you make changes in client side code (GWT) simply refreshing your browser and the changes will take effect. It runs in Super Dev Mode.

Comment: my project is  also GWT-Spring-Maven project. and my eclipse is also configure for super dev mode. in my eclipse mvn gwt:run or mvn gwt:debug command not showing

Comment: Hi probably you misunderstood. gwt:run and gwt:debug will be available after setting the `gwt-maven-plugin` in your `pom.xml`. I edited my answer and added a sample.

Comment: ok but I am getting the following Exception :---The parameters 'runTarget' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.3.0-1:run are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Comment: Have you configured the `runTarget` property correctly? The value in my answer is a sample, an example, I cannot know what your project is/should be.

Comment: yes I set  run target as <runTarget>/Application.html</runTarget> but getting 503 error

Comment: And you are sure that this change is correct for your project? Have you checked your module gwt.xml? Your host page has the same name as mine, Application.html? and your module name is .. empty?

Comment: yes my host page is FishingEntry.html and entry-point class=is FishingEntry l i think html path is not in proper way

Comment: Can you post your module.gwt.xml file? It should contain your module name, the runTarget should be : module name/FishingEntry.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108518/discussion-between-nitin-verma-and-elefasgr).

Comment: `gwt-maven-plugin:2.3.0` This is old! Dies that version match your version of GWT? It **has** to match, that's how Mojo's Maven Plugin for GWT works.

Answer (score 0):

I setup super dev mode like this.

1. Set the launcherDir in the configuration to the war output path, target/webapp folder.
2. Then run, gwt:run-codeserver